# Firestore taking too much time to update from flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, listen

I want to update a field of a particular document in firestore while listening to any change in its value. So basically, when the field 'call' is found to be 1, we will update it again back to 0 after printing a message. However, it takes too much time to update. On the other hand, updating the same field using python is way quicker. Please advise me what should be done.

```
 FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('joystick')
        .snapshots()
        .listen((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {

      var  firestoreList = querySnapshot.docs;
      var data = firestoreList.first.data();

      var callval = firestoreList.first.get('call');
      print("call value while listening ${callval}");

      if(callval == 1){
        print("call value is 1 ");

        //makecall();
        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('joystick').doc('data').update({'call':0});
        call = firestoreList.first.get('call');
        print("Next call value is ${call}");

        if(call == 0){
          print("updated!");
          callval = 0;
        }
      }
   }).onError((e) => print(e));
```

Comment: A document write takes as long as it takes.  You can't write code to speed it up.  You're at the mercy of the throughput and latency of the network connection being used.

Answer (score 1):

Document writing takes as long as it takes and depends on network connection speed. But you can speed up uploading data by compressing them. Dart has a useful tool as `GZip`. `GZip` can compress `String` data up to 99% You can `decode/encode` data in many ways even `HttpClient` can `autoUncompress` it :).

```dart
import 'dart:io';

// Send compressed data.
Future<void> sendCompressed() async {
  final gzip = GZipCodec();
  // You can convert any data to JSON string with `dart:convert`.
  const String jsonToSend = '{"field": "Some JSON to send to the server."}';
  // Original Data.
  final List<int> original = utf8.encode(jsonToSend);
  // Compress data.
  final List<int> compressed = gzip.encode(original);
  // Send compressed to db.
  print(compressed);
}

// Get compressed data.
Future<void> getCompressed() async {
  final gzip = GZipCodec();
  // Get compressed data from the data base.
  final List<int> compressed = await http.get('https://data.com');
  // Decompress
  final List<int> decompress = gzip.decode(compressed);
  // Decode back to String (JSON)
  final String decoded = utf8.decode(decompress);
  // Do what you want with decoded data.
  print(decoded);
}
```